# Invoke https api call using powershell

Tags: powershell

Can any one help on how to get start time, end time , duration and execute an API using powershell script

example
Need to execute below sample API

Get current UTC time in this format "2021-05-22T12:15:27.000027" and store in this variable

StartTimeInUTC = 2021-05-22T12:15:27.000027
invoke below API

https:test.com/${StartTimeInUTC}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below code shows how you can call API in powershell.

```
$StartTimeInUTC = Get-Date -Format o | ForEach-Object { $_ -replace ":", "." }
Write-Host $StartTimeInUTC
$url = "https://test.com/${StartTimeInUTC}"

Write-Host $url

$webrequest = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -SessionVariable websession  -UseBasicParsing


$EndTimeInUTC = Get-Date -Format o | ForEach-Object { $_ -replace ":", "." }

Write-Host $EndTimeInUTC
```